# Weird UITableView behavior after expand/collapse the last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I want to achieve is that: cell can expand/collapse when clicking on the label inside of it. The cell size should be remembered so that when the user scrolls back to the cell, it should be the size it is used to be. I setup the cell using Auto Layout with all the views assigned height constraint. When the user clicks on the label, I change the cell height by changing the label's height constraint:

```
func triggerExpandCollapse(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
    guard let cell  = cell as? ActivityTableViewCell, let indexPath = self.activitiesTableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    if !self.expandedCellIndex.insert(indexPath.row).inserted {
        self.expandedCellIndex.remove(indexPath.row)
        cell.descLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 60
    }
    else {
        cell.descLabelHeightConstraint.constant = cell.descLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height
    }

    self.activitiesTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.activitiesTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

And also config the cell's height before returning every cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.TableViewCellID.activity, for: indexPath)
    guard let activityCell = cell as? ActivityTableViewCell else {
        return cell
    }

    activityCell.delegate = self
    if self.expandedCellIndex.contains(indexPath.row) {
        activityCell.descLabelHeightConstraint.constant = activityCell.descLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height
    }
    else {
        activityCell.descLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 60
    }
    activityCell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return activityCell
}
```

I also enable auto layout by:

```
self.activitiesTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.activitiesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000
```

So far the cells can expand/collapse with normal scroll behavior except the last one! When I expand the last one and scroll up, the `activitiesTableView` looks "jumping" a short distance. Detail can refer to the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5mCJQtkVog)

I have no idea how to debug right now. Does anyone have some ideas about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After having a sleep to clear my mind, I had some tryings and figured out a way to have expand/collapse cell with animation and smooth UITableView scrolling, what I have done can be described in the following changes:

1. include `layoutIfNeeded` of the cell, `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` in  the animation block where to trigger cell expand/collapse. Full version is:

   ```
   func triggerExpandCollapse(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
       guard let cell = cell as? DonationsTableViewCell, let indexPath = self.donationsTableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

       if !self.expandedCellsSet.insert(indexPath.row).inserted    // Collapse
       {
           self.expandedCellsSet.remove(indexPath.row)
           cell.projectDescLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 60
       }
       else    // Expand
       {
           cell.projectDescLabelHeightConstraint.constant = cell.projectDescLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height
       }

       UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.TimeDuration.cellExpandCollapse, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { 
           cell.layoutIfNeeded()
           self.donationsTableView.beginUpdates()
           self.donationsTableView.endUpdates()
       }, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
2. In this case, the scrolling indicator changes its size while the user scrolling. That is because the `estimatedRowHeight` is too different from the actual cell height. I would suggest implementing `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)` to provide approximate height for each cell. Note that if the returned value is too large, the expand/collapse behaviour will be abnormal

I would be very grateful if anyone has better solutions!